# State of kafka stream processor when restoring StateStore from changelog kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What would be state of kafka streams application when it is restoring `StateStore` from kafka changelog topic? In which state `StreamThread` would be in? If restoring takes too long, will it trigger rebalances?

Comment: Why not add a state listener to see what happens? https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.StateListener.html

Comment: @cricket_007: Thanks for your pointers. I am learning those concepts and not aware of intriciases. I will definitely refer to what you have pointed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as a `StreamThread` is restoring, its state will be `PARTITION_ASSIGNED` (cf https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L75-L116). Even if the thread is in this state it won't drop out of the consumer group, because it will `pause()` all its input topic partitions and still call `poll()` on a regular basis to avoid hitting `max.poll.interval.ms` config.

Note thought, that the "state" of a `StreamThread` is something internal and not the same as the state of a `KafkaStreams` instance. The state of a `KafkaStreams` instance depends on all the states of its `StreamsThreads`.